# Pack static libs into single shared lib, paho-mqtt not working

Tags: c, build, shared-libraries, paho

I'm trying to pack several static libs into single shared lib. Everything works except `paho-mqtt3c.a`. In `CMakeLists.txt`, I have included the header files:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/paho-mqttc)
```

and linked the paho-mqtt lib just like the others:

```
target_link_libraries(baselib -lpaho-mqtt3c -ljansson -lhiredis -lsqlite3)
```

There is no error message but `nm baselib.so | grep MQTT` returns nothing, while all the other libs are listed correctly. I also tested `paho-mqtt3c.a` and it worked as expected. So what might be the problem？

Comment: Does any module in the target shared library actually *reference* anything from the paho-mqtt library? If not, the linker may well optimize it away, as it's not being used.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's exactly the cause of the problem, thank you so much!! BTW, is it possible to force the linker to link libs that are not actually used?

Comment: Not sure about a *general* system for non-Windows shared libraries but, IIRC, the paho_mqtt code has a setting ( a `#define XXX`, somewhere) that selects between a static library build and a dynamic/shared library; I guess you should select the latter, which will mark the relevant (public) routines as exported.